# Why will JDateChooser not receive focus events

Tags: java, swing, jdatechooser, focuslistener

I am trying to add a `FocusAdapter` to a `JDateChooser` swing item, but the `focusGained()` method is not firing, neither through a tab focus or a mouse-click...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 1;

    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    panel.add(textField, c);
    JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser(new Date());
    dateChooser.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent evt) {
            System.out.println(evt.getSource()); // This line never runs
        }
    });

    c.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(dateChooser, c);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Frustrating... Am I missing something small?

Comment: It's because the `JDateChooser` doesn't receive focus, its editor does

Comment: @MadProgrammer, should make it an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Had to look it up first ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [JavaDocs](http://max-server.myftp.org/jcalendar/ibuild/dist/doc/api/com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser.html), you need to get the UI component that is acting as the editor for the `JDateChooser`

```
JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser(new Date());
IDateEditor editor = dateChooser.getDateEditor();
JComponent comp = editor.getUiComponent();
comp.addFocusListener(...);
```

Comment: Just for confusion, I've definitely added a `FocusAdapter` straight to the `JDateChooser` before (I'm looking at the code) and it worked, but I wasn't able to replicate the functionality. Not sure why it works in one program but not in another...

Comment: Either way, you are right and this is the proper way to do it, even if the other way worked on a fluke...